# What is the most efficient way to do equivalent of #select on every entry in the database

Tags: ruby

I have some input names that I need to compare with names in my DB. The issue is that the names are not exact matches, so I can't do a simple `Person.find_by(name: name)`. I will use JaroWinkler distance, with a threshold setting.

How can I calculate this for each db entry, for each input name, and select only those above the given threshold?

Here is how I am currently doing it:

Get an array of `[[lowercase_name, id], [lowercase_name, id]]`. Then do a map/compact on it.

```
class Klass

  require "jaro_winkler"

  JARO_WINKLER_MARGIN = 0.80

  def initialize
    @names = Person.all.map { |e| [e.name.downcase, e.id] }
  end

  def get_from_db(name)
    valid_ids = @names.map do |n|
      n[1] if JaroWinkler.distance(n[0], company_name.downcase) > JARO_WINKLER_MARGIN
    end.compact
    return Person.find(valid_ids)
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do this IN the db? It seems bad to have the entire DB of names in an array, because 1. it wastes memory, 2. the DB could change, so I dont know how to keep it up to date (I also dont want to create the array before each comparison).

Comment: I think you should use pg_similarity extension, hopefully you are using postgres

Comment: https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity

Comment: BTW, since you have not specified the database you use: [Jaro-Winkler similarity stored proc for MySQL](https://androidaddicted.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/jaro-winkler-sql-code/).

Comment: Just curious, why are you using map and compact instead of select and map?  I think the latter would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few assumptions about this situation, and suggest an approach in which the Jaro-Winkler distances are maintained within the database.

Here are the key assumptions:

- You need to perform this calculation often enough that the runtime cost of the array-based approach is significantly high or impactful to the performance of the database
- You have the ability to manage / update the database schema
- Insert/update on the data will only be made through the Rails application
- You're fundamentally OK with keeping cached data in the database (deviating from normal form)

If all of these assumptions hold, then it's possible to create a new column on the Person table and store the Jaro-Winkler distance value there.  This will allow the calculations to be done only when the record is initially created or when the source columns (e.g. name, company_name) are changed.

So, the very first thing to do would be to create the migration.  Something like this should do just nicely:

```
rails generate migration AddJwDistanceToPeople
```

Then, edit the `db/migrate/2016xxxxxxxxxx_add_jw_distance_to_people.rb`, like so:

```
require "jaro_winkler"

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class AddJwDistanceToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :people, :jw_distance, :float
    add_index :people, :jw_distance

    Person.reset_column_information

    Person.where(jw_distance: nil).order('updated_at ASC').each do |person|
        person.jw_distance = JaroWinkler.distance(person.name.downcase, person.company_name.downcase)
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :people, :jw_distance
  end
end
```

This does a few important things.  First, it creates a local version of `Person`, so that there are no migration issues with any implementation details of `Person`, always a migration best practice.  Next, it adds the `jw_distance` column and index to the `People` table and resets the column information to make the new column available within the migration.  Finally, it processes all existing records where the `jw_distance` is empty and updates the value.

Once that's complete, locate and edit the Person model, in `app/models/person.rb`:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_jw_distance

private
  def set_jw_distance
    self.jw_distance = JaroWinkler.distance(self.name.downcase, self.company_name.downcase)
  end
end
```

Note that the `set_jw_distance` function can always be optimized to only recalculate after checking whether either `name` or `company_name` have changed, using the [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) helpers.

After this is done and in place, the original `Klass` code can be updated to perform a reasonably optimal query:

```
require "jaro_winkler"

class Klass
  JARO_WINKLER_MARGIN = 0.80

  def get_from_db(name)
    return Person.where("jw_distance > ?", JARO_WINKLER_MARGIN)
  end
end
```

The `Person.where()` query can now optimally retrieve only those person records in which the Jaro-Winkler distance exceeds the margin threshold.  The query probably can't be tuned much more quickly

The performance of this solution will be impacted in the following ways:

- Inserts and updates will be slightly slower; depending on the implementation, this may or may not be noticeable
- The Person.where() query will be far more performant than the original, and will likely be noticeable with only moderate data volumes

While this solution may or may not be a suitable for the original implementation / purpose, it does show how to effectively establish and maintain database caching for computed values and how to use them in subsequent queries.  The original problem given is a terrific example of situation in which database-level caching may be considered, provided acceptance of the list of assumptions given at the outset of this answer.